# How can I provide current data definitions for a column when changing the column name in MariaDB (via PHP)?

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a function that shall modify column names in a MariaDB table. If I use MySQL or MariaDB version 10.5.2+ I can use the following simple query:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME COLUMN c_old TO c_new;
```

However, in older versions of MariaDB I am forced to use the more complicated `CHANGE` command, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c_old TO c_new [data_definitions];
```

The *data_definitions* could be for example `varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Column for the username'`. It is the creation of the data definition string that causes some trouble for me.

So, I wonder how I can get/create the *data definitions* string in PHP in order to make the correct query for changing column names. My code looks like this for the moment:

```
<?php
function rename_column($mysqli, $table, $current_name, $new_name) {
 
    $data_definitions = // How do I find/get these in a simple way?

    $sql = "ALTER TABLE {$table} CHANGE `{$current_name}` `{$new_name}` {$data_definitions}";
    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!res) {
        echo "'$sql' failed. Error: " . $mysqli->error; 
        return false; 
    }
    return $res;
}
?>
```

I have thought of making a query like `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE field = '$current_name'` in order to read each data_definition and build a string for each definition, but I wonder if it can be solved in a simpler way?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ?

Comment: @TaaviTiitsu Thanks! Perfect answer... I'll take it from there :)